# Where digit sum matches digit sum of the square - formal name?

Tags: decimal-expansion, natural-numbers

Just came across this.

[image]

The UK equivalent is 999, for which the square is 998,001 - which interestingly shares the same digit sum.  I just wonder if this has a name and/or any literature?  I note there are some [applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) of digit sum.

Comment: See OEIS sequence [A058369](https://oeis.org/A058369) and Hare, Laishram & Stoll reference there.

Comment: A number is congruent mod 9 to its digit sum, so a necessary condition is that $n^2 \equiv n \pmod{9}$ which requires that $n \equiv 0$ or $n \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$.  This shows at a glance it can't work for $n=911$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks. Wanna make that the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Made from comment to answer at OP's request]

See OEIS sequence [A058369](https://oeis.org/A058369) and Hare, Laishram & Stoll reference there.